# Extending a public hot spot

Tags: hotspot

The airport folks provide a wi fi hot spot about 200 feet from my steel aiplane hangar.
I cannot receive the signal in the hangar. I can receive the signal outside the man-door of the hangar.
How can I get the signal in the hangar?

Comment: A WiFi extender might work if you can place it in a window (if there are any) and you can get power there. You will probably need approval from the system administrator for any such installation.

Answer (score 0):

A hangar is like a faraday cage, and its metal will block the wifi signals.

Your only option is to get a landline inside the hangar with a WIFI access point. This is not extending the public hot spot though, but rather lay a line from a wired connection to the hangar.

Alternatively you would need to have a device outside the hangar that would act as a wifi client, which shares its internet to a lan cable. The lan cable then goes inside the hangar and from there to a wifi accesspoint. Note that this is a really bad idea because it will generate a slow connection. Getting a land line to the hanger is likely going to be cheaper in the long run.

Comment: Aren't there wi fi extenders I could put near the open door?

Comment: I suppose that could work, but you have to realize that you have to keep the door open all the time for it to work, and it highly depends on the orientation of the doors in relation to where the signal is coming from. But that would still give you a bad signal where a landline would be optimal. You may be able to use ethernet over powerline adapters to bridge the area outside, depending on where the power comes in. If a line goes from the main area to the hangar, you could use a poweroutlet in that area (maybe you need to install one) to redirect network traffic to the hangar.